# CodeIgniter Rest Server dealing with JSON POST request

Tags: json, codeigniter, rest, post, request

I am trying to make my JSON POST request working, when I set it to form-encoded request I can display all the `?args=values&args=values` by `$this->response($this->post(),200);` but when I change id to json-encoded POST input, I get as response `[]` - why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a difference between POST parameters and a HTTP body... well, at least as far as PHP is concerned.

You want to look at `$this->request->body`.