# How can I get http request body data in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am having trouble getting JSON encoded data POSTed to my CI controller from my IOS obj-c client. I believe that my problem is the same as the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569150/codeigniter-rest-server-dealing-with-json-post-request). But I cannot find any documentation on a 'request' object on the CodeIgniter site. How can I view/parse the data in an http request body?

$this->request->body  ??

Thanks!

Comment: For getting data sent through body to your controller you can use `$request->getJSON();`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using

```
$jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

The above will read the request body from the input request and then decodes the JSON to an associative array.

I would still be interested in refactoring this code if CI has a wrapper for reading input stream http body data as I am above. Fairly new to this framework.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use
`$this->input->raw_input_stream`

Answer (score 4):

The "request" object mentioned in that post belongs to a package named "codeigniter-restserver". You can find more info [here](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver).

The accepted answer is a working one, but CodeIgniter does provide `$this->input->raw_input_stream` that gives you exactly what you need. So to write things the CodeIgniter way, you should use:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream, true);
```

And you'll notice that the source code of `raw_input_stream` also uses the `file_get_contents('php://input')` method.

Answer (score 4):

To keep using CI native mode I do this:

```
$_POST = json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream, true);
```

then

```
$value = $this->input->post($fieldName);
```

Comment: What is CI Native Mode? Right now my request only works via raw_input_stream, but the docs say post('key') should work. I can't find anything on CI native mode. Thanks!

Comment: By "native mode" I mean CI's official API
In this example, the second row is far more readable the the first one, so I prefer to temper the $_POST variable at a lower level, and then use the official API methods - i.e. $this->input->post() - inside models/view/controllers

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with codeigniter version >=4 then you can try this:

```
$requestBody = json_decode($this->request->getBody());

$user = $requestBody->user;
```

If you're working with version 3 , you can try

```
$this->input->post('user', TRUE);
```

Comment: you should add one for CI3, $this->input->raw_input_stream to get body or raw post

Answer (score -5):

From the CodeIgniter Documentation for CI 2.1 I see the Input class provides the following call

```
 $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter
```

This way you can make sure the request body is XSS filtered

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question asked