# Restfull API with codeigniter Not geting value from post url

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter

I am creating a Restful API with CodeIgniter, and I am not getting the correct value when I am calling the API through the POST method.

```
public function register_user_post()
{
    var_dump($this->post());
}
```

I am getting a blank array every time.

Comment: [$this->input...](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#accessing-form-data)?

Comment: [How can I get http request body data in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346730/how-can-i-get-http-request-body-data-in-codeigniter)

Comment: show how u r posting data to `register_user_post`

Comment: ATBB56E7JKWDcCwsHKSS5xTwavFs0D8304A1

Answer (score 0):

You have missed input in your code,change your code to

```
public function register_user_post()
{
    var_dump($this->input->post());
}
```